# Symfony2 - Security/Classe de usuário customizado

Tags: php, symfony

Estou aprendendo a mexer um pouco com Symfony2 e surgiu uma certa dúvida.
Seguindo o próprio documento do Symfony, ele ensina criar um formulário de login simples, onde implementa a interface `UserInterface`, com os campos `$username` e `$password` e alguns outros.

Caso eu quisesse criar essa classe de usuário diferente, com nomes `$usuario` e `$senha`, o que eu preciso saber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há problemas em ter o nome da propriedades desejadas, desde que você retorne corretamente aquilo que a `interface` implementada exija.

Uma interface no PHP "força" que a classe tenha os métodos que estão determinados nela.

Então, o que você usa a interface `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface` , o que você precisa fazer é retornar `$senha` para o método `getPassword` e `usuario` para o método `getUsername`.

Existem também outros métodos que precisam ser implementados dessa interface

Leituras recomendadas:

- [How to Create a custom User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html)
- [Symfony API - Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html)

Exemplo tirado da página do `Symfony`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Security\User;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;

class WebserviceUser implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface
{
    private $usuario;
    private $senha;
    private $salt;
    private $roles;

    public function __construct($usuario, $senha, $salt, array $roles)
    {
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
        $this->senha = $senha;
        $this->salt = $salt;
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->senha;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof WebserviceUser) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->senha !== $user->getPassword()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->salt !== $user->getSalt()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->usuario !== $user->getUsername()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```